# Autopair and Python strings

Tags: python, string, emacs, quotes

I use `autopair-mode` globally for intelligent quote/paren/bracket pairing. It helps in most situations, except one.

It's kind of a pain in the ass using Python's multi-quote strings. Typing quote once gives me `"|"`, another quote gets me `""|`, a third quote gets me `"""|"`, a *fourth* quote gies `""""|`, a **fifth** quote gives me `"""""|`, and a sixth quote finally gets me to `""""""|`. At which point I need to hop back three spaces to get what I actually wanted the whole time, which is `"""|"""`.

Is there a pre-built (or easy) way of getting `autopair` to have the behavior that hitting quote three times automatically gives me `"""|"""` instead of the quote-shuffle described above?

Comment: [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) might well support this. It's a more recent library, and sounds extremely flexible. (I don't use anything like this myself, so I can't say for sure.)

Comment: Ah, except its [documentation](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Pair-management) says that no pair's opening can be a prefix for another pair's opening, so perhaps not.

Comment: Did you try adding `autopair-python-triple-quote-action` to `autopair-handle-action-fns` as described here: https://github.com/capitaomorte/autopair

Comment: @immerrr - Had that been an answer, I'd have upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following to my `.emacs` gave me the desired behavior:

```lisp
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (setq autopair-handle-action-fns
                    (list #'autopair-default-handle-action
                          #'autopair-python-triple-quote-action))))
```

Found in [the More Tricks section](https://github.com/capitaomorte/autopair#more-tricks) of the documentation linked by *immerrr* in their comment.